# Defining Cycles based on Thresholds

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set containing nonuniform 30,000 rows that consist of three variables: Time, Chamber and temperature. The two chambers heat and cool at different rates and I need to assign a cycle count every time a positive slope above 75 degrees. I am trying to convert the x-axis from time, to cycle of heating and cooling.
[This would classify as one cycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEela.png)

I have found two similar issues here: [How to count the amount of times (frequency) that data passes through a certain threshold in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69567545/how-to-count-the-amount-of-times-frequency-that-data-passes-through-a-certain) and [time between max and min of cycles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65009845/time-between-max-and-min-of-cycles) but both don't get me to the my end goal. Utilizing `data.table::rleid((lead(Chamber_temperature, order_by = Chamber_ID) > threshold)` counts at both the positive and the negative slope as two different crosses of the threshold.  If I include `data.table::rleid((Chamber_temperature <= threshold | lead(Chamber_temperature, order_by = Chamber_ID) > threshold)` I get a cycle of single row for lead, and another cycle with multiple rows which are above the threshold. Ultimately this seems to be double counting the number of cycles as well.

In this example data set there are two complete cycles:

```r
Time=c(100674751, 100674851, 100674951, 100675051, 100675151, 100675251, 100675351, 100675451, 100675551, 100675651, 100675751, 100675851, 100675951, 100676051, 100676151, 100676251, 100676351, 100676451, 100676551, 100676651, 100676751, 100676851, 100676951, 100677051, 100677151, 100677251, 100677351, 100677451, 100677551, 100677651, 100677751, 100677851, 100677951, 100678051, 100678151, 100678251, 100678351, 100678451, 100678551, 100678651, 100678751, 100678851, 100678951, 100679051, 100679151, 100679251, 100679351, 100679451, 100679551, 100679651, 100679751, 100679851, 100679951, 100680051, 100680151, 100680251, 100680351, 100680451, 100680551, 100680651, 100680751, 100680851, 100680951, 100681051, 100681151, 100681251, 100681351, 100681451, 100681551, 100681651, 100681751, 100681851, 100681951, 100682051, 100682151, 100682251, 100682351, 100682451, 100682551, 100682651, 100682751, 100682851, 100682951, 100683051, 100683151, 100683251, 100683351, 100683451, 100683551, 100683651, 100683751, 100683851, 100683951, 100684051, 100684151, 100684251, 100684351, 100684451, 100684551, 100684651, 100684751, 100684851, 100684951, 100685051, 100685151, 100685251, 100685351, 100685451, 100685551, 100685651, 100685751, 100685851, 100685951, 100686051, 100686151, 100686251, 100686351, 100686451, 100686551, 100686651, 100686751, 100686851, 100686951, 100687051, 100687151, 100687251, 100687351, 100687451, 100687551, 100687651, 100687751, 100687851, 100687951, 100688051, 100688151, 100688251, 100688351, 100688451, 100688551, 100688651, 100688751, 100688851, 100688951, 100689051, 100689151, 100689251, 100689351, 100689451, 100689551, 100689651, 100689751, 100689851, 100689951, 100690051, 100690151, 100690251, 100690351, 100690451, 100690551, 100690651, 100690751, 100690851, 100690951, 100691051, 100691151, 100691251, 100691351, 100691451, 100691551, 100691651, 100691751, 100691851, 100691951, 100692051, 100692151, 100692251, 100692351, 100692451, 100692551, 100692651, 100692751, 100692851, 100692951, 100693051, 100693151, 100693251)  
Chamber_ID=c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1) 
Temp=c(56.8, 58.2, 59.7, 59.7, 61.4, 63.2, 63.2, 65.0, 66.8, 66.8, 68.7, 70.5, 70.5, 72.3, 74.1, 74.1, 75.9, 77.6, 77.6, 79.3, 81.0, 81.0, 82.7, 84.4, 84.4, 87.9, 86.6, 86.6, 85.4, 84.1, 84.1, 82.9, 81.8, 81.8, 80.6, 79.5, 79.5, 78.3, 77.2, 77.2, 76.2, 75.1, 75.1, 74.1, 73.0, 73.0, 72.0, 71.1, 71.1, 70.1, 69.1, 69.1, 68.2, 67.2, 67.2, 66.3, 65.4, 65.4, 64.6, 63.7, 63.7, 62.8, 62.0, 62.0, 61.2, 60.4, 60.4, 59.6, 58.8, 58.8, 58.0, 57.3, 57.3, 56.8, 58.2, 58.2, 59.7, 61.4, 61.4, 63.2, 65.0, 65.0, 66.9, 68.7, 68.7, 70.5, 72.3, 72.3, 74.1, 75.9, 75.9, 77.6, 79.3, 79.3, 81.0, 82.7, 82.7, 84.4, 86.0, 86.0, 87.7, 89.3, 86.6, 85.3, 85.3, 84.1, 82.9, 82.9, 81.7, 80.6, 80.6, 79.4, 78.3, 78.3, 77.2, 76.1, 76.1, 75.1, 74.1, 74.1, 73.0, 72.0, 72.0, 71.0, 70.1, 70.1, 69.1, 68.1, 68.1, 67.2, 66.3, 66.3, 65.4, 64.5, 64.5, 63.7, 62.8, 62.8, 62.0, 61.2, 61.2, 60.4, 59.6, 59.6, 58.8, 58.0, 58.0, 57.3, 56.5, 56.5, 56.9, 56.9, 58.2, 59.7, 59.7, 61.5, 63.2, 63.2, 65.0, 66.9, 66.9, 68.7, 70.5, 70.5, 72.3, 74.1, 74.1, 75.9, 77.6, 77.6, 79.3, 81.0, 81.0, 82.7, 84.4, 84.4, 86.0, 87.7, 87.7, 89.3, 90.9, 90.9, 92.5, 94.0, 94.0, 95.6)
```

This would be the expected output, with the cycle only increasing when the temperature increases above the threshold, not below.

[image: Expected output]

Comment: Check your data - they have errors I suspect. For example,  `Temp` has a value of `3 90.9,` and it's unclear if `Chamber_ID` value ` 0 1` is supposed to be one or two rows.

Comment: Thanks @socialscientist, I edited the post to fix the errors in the dataset and added an expected result for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cycle **change** can be identified by the following algorithm:

1. Sort your data by `Time`
2. Find rows for which `Temp > 75` returns `TRUE`
3. Within that subset of rows, find rows where `Temp <= 75` returns `TRUE` for the **previous** row.

Once we have identified cycle **changes**, we can obtain a running tally of cycles using `cumsum()`.

I've implemented this in the code below. Since there is ambiguity about what you want to do with `ChamberID`, I've assumed you want to track cycles separating for each of the subgroups defined by the unique values of `ChamberID`.

## Create Data

```r
# Create your original data, stored in a data.frame
df <- data.frame(Time=c(100674751, 100674851, 100674951, 100675051, 100675151, 100675251, 100675351, 100675451, 100675551, 100675651, 100675751, 100675851, 100675951, 100676051, 100676151, 100676251, 100676351, 100676451, 100676551, 100676651, 100676751, 100676851, 100676951, 100677051, 100677151, 100677251, 100677351, 100677451, 100677551, 100677651, 100677751, 100677851, 100677951, 100678051, 100678151, 100678251, 100678351, 100678451, 100678551, 100678651, 100678751, 100678851, 100678951, 100679051, 100679151, 100679251, 100679351, 100679451, 100679551, 100679651, 100679751, 100679851, 100679951, 100680051, 100680151, 100680251, 100680351, 100680451, 100680551, 100680651, 100680751, 100680851, 100680951, 100681051, 100681151, 100681251, 100681351, 100681451, 100681551, 100681651, 100681751, 100681851, 100681951, 100682051, 100682151, 100682251, 100682351, 100682451, 100682551, 100682651, 100682751, 100682851, 100682951, 100683051, 100683151, 100683251, 100683351, 100683451, 100683551, 100683651, 100683751, 100683851, 100683951, 100684051, 100684151, 100684251, 100684351, 100684451, 100684551, 100684651, 100684751, 100684851, 100684951, 100685051, 100685151, 100685251, 100685351, 100685451, 100685551, 100685651, 100685751, 100685851, 100685951, 100686051, 100686151, 100686251, 100686351, 100686451, 100686551, 100686651, 100686751, 100686851, 100686951, 100687051, 100687151, 100687251, 100687351, 100687451, 100687551, 100687651, 100687751, 100687851, 100687951, 100688051, 100688151, 100688251, 100688351, 100688451, 100688551, 100688651, 100688751, 100688851, 100688951, 100689051, 100689151, 100689251, 100689351, 100689451, 100689551, 100689651, 100689751, 100689851, 100689951, 100690051, 100690151, 100690251, 100690351, 100690451, 100690551, 100690651, 100690751, 100690851, 100690951, 100691051, 100691151, 100691251, 100691351, 100691451, 100691551, 100691651, 100691751, 100691851, 100691951, 100692051, 100692151, 100692251, 100692351, 100692451, 100692551, 100692651, 100692751, 100692851, 100692951, 100693051, 100693151, 100693251),  
Chamber_ID=c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
Temp=c(56.8, 58.2, 59.7, 59.7, 61.4, 63.2, 63.2, 65.0, 66.8, 66.8, 68.7, 70.5, 70.5, 72.3, 74.1, 74.1, 75.9, 77.6, 77.6, 79.3, 81.0, 81.0, 82.7, 84.4, 84.4, 87.9, 86.6, 86.6, 85.4, 84.1, 84.1, 82.9, 81.8, 81.8, 80.6, 79.5, 79.5, 78.3, 77.2, 77.2, 76.2, 75.1, 75.1, 74.1, 73.0, 73.0, 72.0, 71.1, 71.1, 70.1, 69.1, 69.1, 68.2, 67.2, 67.2, 66.3, 65.4, 65.4, 64.6, 63.7, 63.7, 62.8, 62.0, 62.0, 61.2, 60.4, 60.4, 59.6, 58.8, 58.8, 58.0, 57.3, 57.3, 56.8, 58.2, 58.2, 59.7, 61.4, 61.4, 63.2, 65.0, 65.0, 66.9, 68.7, 68.7, 70.5, 72.3, 72.3, 74.1, 75.9, 75.9, 77.6, 79.3, 79.3, 81.0, 82.7, 82.7, 84.4, 86.0, 86.0, 87.7, 89.3, 86.6, 85.3, 85.3, 84.1, 82.9, 82.9, 81.7, 80.6, 80.6, 79.4, 78.3, 78.3, 77.2, 76.1, 76.1, 75.1, 74.1, 74.1, 73.0, 72.0, 72.0, 71.0, 70.1, 70.1, 69.1, 68.1, 68.1, 67.2, 66.3, 66.3, 65.4, 64.5, 64.5, 63.7, 62.8, 62.8, 62.0, 61.2, 61.2, 60.4, 59.6, 59.6, 58.8, 58.0, 58.0, 57.3, 56.5, 56.5, 56.9, 56.9, 58.2, 59.7, 59.7, 61.5, 63.2, 63.2, 65.0, 66.9, 66.9, 68.7, 70.5, 70.5, 72.3, 74.1, 74.1, 75.9, 77.6, 77.6, 79.3, 81.0, 81.0, 82.7, 84.4, 84.4, 86.0, 87.7, 87.7, 89.3, 90.9, 90.9, 92.5, 94.0, 94.0, 95.6))
```

## `data.table` Solution

```r
# Convert to data.table
dt <- as.data.table(df)

# Add a 1-period lagged temperature column
dt[order(Time), Temp_lag1 := shift(Temp, 1), by = Chamber_ID]

# Add indicator for whether a cycle change occurs
dt[order(Time), 
   cycle_change := ifelse(Temp > 75 & Temp_lag1 <= 75, 1, 0),
   by = Chamber_ID]

# Add cycle tracker (add 1 so first cycle is 1 not 0)
dt[order(Time), 
   cycle_id := cumsum(cycle_change) + 1, 
   by = Chamber_ID]

# Print distribution of cycles across chambers
table(chamber_id = dt$Chamber_ID, cycle_id = dt$cycle_id)
#>           cycle_id
#> chamber_id  1  2  3  4
#>          0  8 37 39  9
#>          1  8 36 39 10
```

## `dplyr` Solution

```r
result <- df %>%
  group_by(Chamber_ID) %>%
  arrange(Time) %>%
  mutate(
    Temp_lag1 = lag(Temp, 1),
    cycle_change = if_else(Temp > 75 & Temp_lag1 <= 75, 1, 0),
    cycle_id = cumsum(cycle_change) + 1
  )

table(result$Chamber_ID, result$cycle_id)
#>    
#>      1  2  3  4
#>   0  8 37 39  9
#>   1  8 36 39 10
```

According to the above, there are 4 cycles per chamber, with the longest durations being the second and third cycles.

Comment: That works great and was what I was looking to accomplish with tracking the chamber subgroup cycles separately, I have mostly working in Tidy, but the data.table:: solution works well.

Comment: @Charlie_Dont_Surf I added a `dplyr` solution.